Spring Boot Java Process create file with tomcat user
We have a java spring boot application running (jdk11) in k8s. This application does some business logic and creates file as below. The user which has been creating the files are tomcat. The downstream reads this file from the same location.

Recently, we upgraded to jdk21 and noticed that the user for file creation has been changed from "tomcat" to "4294967294" and the downstream is broken with permission denied errors.
Not sure how this user is selected which running the application. Can someone please help to get some pointers here?


What does your docker file look like?

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Without seeing any application code or the container setup it's very hard to tell what might be the problem.  I'd also ask whether this user ID change is causing any operational problems or if it's just something you've noticed.  Please do not upload images of code/data/errors; when you do edit the question, make sure to include the code as plain text, and replace the screen shots of directory listings with plain text as well.
